# How to Add/Remove value from a list?

Tags: jquery

I need to add and remove items from a list of integers.  There will be no repeats in the list. I will pass the list to a query and display the results.  Right now, I just need to be able to start with an empty list and as the user selects items, the list will be populated.

The idea is that when a user clicks on the first time, the item will be bolded and its ID will be added to the list. The second time an item is clicked on, the item will be unbolded and the ID will be removed from the list.  Easy, right?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    MyList = "";

$(".Cat").live("click", function() {
    CurrentClass = $(this).attr("class");
    // CLICKED
        if (CurrentClass == "Cat") {
        $(this).addClass("Bold");
            NewItem = $(this).attr("id");
            // ADD ITEM TO LIST
            MyList = 
        // UNCLICKED 
        } else {
        $(this).removeClass("Bold");
            NewItem = $(this).attr("id");
            // REMOVE ITEM FROM LIST
            MyList =   
    }
});

});
</script>

<span id="1" class="Cat">1</span>

<span id="2" class="Cat">2</span>

<span id="3" class="Cat">3</span>
```

Comment: The list starts out completely empty:     MyList = "";

Comment: There is no list in your HTML. Did you mean, perhaps, an _array_? This question is not clear.

Comment: The list would start out empty. When the user clicks on an item in the span tags with the class of Cat, the id will be added to MyList.  So, if they click on 1, the value of 1 will be added to MyList.  If they click on 1 again, the value of 1 will be removed from MyList.

Comment: Again, where is this "list"? What do you really mean by "list"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd us an array and keep it simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var MyList = new Array();

$(".Cat").live("click", function() {
    CurrentClass = $(this).attr("class");
    // CLICKED
        if (CurrentClass == "Cat") {
        $(this).addClass("Bold");
            NewItem = $(this).attr("id");
            // ADD ITEM TO LIST
            MyList.push(NewItem); 
        // UNCLICKED 
        } else {
        $(this).removeClass("Bold");
            NewItem = $(this).attr("id");
            // REMOVE ITEM FROM LIST
            MyList.splice( $.inArray(NewItem, MyList), 1 );  
    }
});

});
```

Once you have this array populated, displaying it as an actual comma-separated list is as simple as `MyList.join(',')`

Comment: I think this is the answer that I am looking for.  And why would you use an array rather than a list?

Comment: Ultimately it depends on what you want to do with the data. An array keeps each selected item clearly separated. Doing it as a string leaves you with, well, just a single string.

Comment: An array will allow you more options for data manipulation, but ultimately its up to your application whether or not an array is appropriate. For this case I believe it is.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  It was a flawless solution.

Answer (score 1):

initialize list:

```
var myList = []
```

add:

```
myList.push(NewItem)
```

remove:

```
myList.splice( $.inArray(NewItem, myList), 1 );
```

I think that was the main question, bolding/unbolding the item is usually done through adding/removing a class. And I see you've already done that.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely sounds like you want an array. But here's an example that keeps MyList simply as a string:

http://jsfiddle.net/bf8wE/1/

Comment: I really like this jsfiddle.net site.  I am thinking this is a great way to work out solutions to really tough problems.  Thanks for your answer. It was pretty accurate.